Android Kotlin - SubFile or MemoryMappedFile?
I have a file that is a package of other files. (essentially concatenation of files)
In my app I have a several things that use normal files(audio, images, video, etc).
But because I'm packing these files up into collections I cannot just pass them to these routines that use files. (I'm actually passing Paths or path strings so I'll have to modify that but some stuff using files are library code)
What I need to do is pass them a file that is really only looking at the file inside the "collection file". (so the reading should be limited only to an interval inside the file)
Is there anything in kotlin or java that can dot his for me? basically I pass the starting and end or length and the file and it returns a file that for all practical purposes looks as if that chunk of the file is an actual file? It's all read only so.
What I do not want to do is write the file out to a temp file and load that. That is pointless and a waste of time and longevity.
I'm thinking I might have to extend File but I'm hoping it's already been done. I can't find anything though.
To be clear:
mFileDescriptor = MemoryFileUtil.getParcelFileDescriptor(file!!)
throws java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MemoryFile.getParcelFileDescriptor []
If I write file to a tmp file it works fine. I've tried
mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromFd(file!!.fd.toInt())
mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.dup(file!!.fd)
using the getFileDescriptor in MemoryFile but it fails too.
and others which all try to get the MemoryFile file descriptor using reflection. The error is useless in explaining what really is going on but it seems that it has to do with the descriptor either being invalid for ParcelFileDescriptor not working with MemoryFile.
Even if I get what seems to be a valid filedescriptor then
PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor!!)
throws java.io.IOException: file not in PDF format or corrupted
I don't know why it's throwing this error since if I save the file directly I can open it just fine.
Either the descriptor is not correct or the MemoryFile is not acting as a real enough File to pass the PDF test.

    final long size;
    try {
        Os.lseek(input.getFileDescriptor(), 0, OsConstants.SEEK_SET);
        size = Os.fstat(input.getFileDescriptor()).st_size;
    } catch (ErrnoException ee) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("file descriptor not seekable");
    }
    mInput = input;

    synchronized (sPdfiumLock) {
        mNativeDocument = nativeCreate(mInput.getFd(), size);

The code crashes on nativeCreate with the "invalid pdf". Os.fstat is returning 0 size
The issue seems to be that PdfRenderer simply does not work with MemoryFile.

Can you pass an InputStream or does it have to be a File?

@k314159 It has to be a file or a filedescriptor. It's for PdfRenderer. I tried MemoryFile and using a hack to get the filedescriptor but it fails with various errors without much info of what is going on(at best I got an init error). The MemoryFile has the correct data. Basically the way my apps work I have a pdf in memory and trying to use PdfRenderer to get it to work. It works with a file but I see no need to do that. E.g., if I save the MemoryFile buf to a temp file then load that.  There should be no reason for that step.

also, the hack I'm using is to get the file descriptor from MemoryFile which I found SO which is essentially just using reflection to call the getFileDescriptor method in memory file.
